# What is the correct stackExchange site to ask about conceptual question about computer systems?

Tags: discussion

What is the correct stackExchange site to ask about conceptual question about computer systems? Is programmers better or computer science one better?

I am not really planning on asking anything related to actual coding or debugging at all though.

It was request to provide examples, so here are the types of questions I plan on asking:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234004/how-does-fds-flat-datacenter-storage-make-optimizations-around-locality-unnece

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23155/why-does-appending-permutations-of-servers-at-the-end-of-hash-table-avoid-bottle

Some hypothetical examples are as follows:

Another hypothetical example could be, I would like to discuss X detail of map reduce (and provide the link to the paper) or Y detail of two-phase commit, Z detail of Paxos (and provide a link of Lamport's paper) or P detail of Spanner, or W detail of EPaxos. etc

Comment: Can you give us an example (or two) of the kind of question that you're thinking about asking?

Comment: Yes, I have already asked one while I was waiting a response for this question:

http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23155/why-does-appending-permutations-of-servers-at-the-end-of-hash-table-avoid-bottle

Comment: I guess my thought for systems question is on the lines of, I have read some systems paper and would like to discuss some section of it with someone (and provide the link to it of course, as I did to the sample question).

Comment: Another hypothetical example could be, I would like to discuss X detail of map reduce (and provide the link to the paper) or Y detail of two-phase commit, Z detail of Paxos (and provide a link of Lamport's paper) etc. Does that more or less make sense?

Comment: That particular question appears to be received OK on CS - it already has an up vote. Questions about algorithms and data structures, system architecture and design, and other topics are on-topic here. It probably depends on the kind of answers that you want. The community here tends to be more practical and oriented toward designing, building, and deploying software systems. CS is more mathematical and "academic" in nature, but they also accept questions on algorithms, data structures, system architecture, and [so on](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: On your opinion, just to get a better sense, if I posted that question on programmers, would it be ok/appropriate?

Comment: When you say systems architecture/design, I would probably ask about the systems design question, so those are ok in programmers, right?

Comment: Also, I tend to consider computer systems a very practical area, so programmers could be the right site if its not a very math heavy question, right?

Comment: If you aren't sure, feel free to post a question where you think it best fits and will get you the kind of answers you want. If it's off-topic for us or we can't give you the kind of answer that you're looking for, and it's as well-written and organized as the one you asked on CS, we can migrate questions. CS is a beta site, so moderators would have to migrate and we tend to be pretty strict with the quality of outgoing questions (especially to a beta site). Whatever you do, directly cross-posting questions without tailoring them for the particular community is not good.

Comment: I have asked one now in programmers, here is another example: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/234004/how-does-fds-flat-datacenter-storage-make-optimizations-around-locality-unnece

Comment: I have collected all the examples in the question.